# CSS shapes rendered before text has empty space between shapes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to render a RateMyProfessor logo next to the names of professors which I created using a CSS [shape generator](http://www.samuelrossille.com/css-shape/#26abe3b3d237y0z2z-6z2z2z0_0z1z-5z1z1z0_1z1z-6z1z1_0z-1z-6z2z2z1)

[image]

```
<td>
    <i class="my-icon"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></i>
    <a
        href=
        "{{ URL_GOES_HERE
        }}"
        @if(
            $class->enroll === $class->max_enroll ||
            $class->enroll === "FULL"
        )
            class="moreMuted"
        @endif
    >
        <span class="instructor">{{ $class->instructor}}</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.my-icon {
  position: relative;
}
.my-icon > i {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #26abe3;
  left: 10.5px;
  top: 0px;
}
.my-icon > i+i {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.5px;
  height: 3.5px;
  background-color: #26abe3;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3.5px;
}
.my-icon > i+i+i {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border: 1.75px solid #b3d237;
  border-bottom: 1.75px solid #b3d237;
  left: 7px;
  top: 0px;
}
.my-icon > i+i+i+i {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #b3d237;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.instructor {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

However, if you zoom right in, there is a big gap between the shapes:

[image]

Only when you zoom out to 150% do you not see a gap.

So my question is:

1. How do I render an icon like that that works in all zoom levels?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

What I did previously was render a `.png` of their icon (with transparency), but since the icon isn't a vector, the edges were not pixel perfect and very blurry. So what I did again was make a pixel icon in Photoshop, saved it as PNG, but *that* was still blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is convert your logo to SVG format.